# how to check virtual memory page size without getconf

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

I need to check vm pagesize on an embedded device running linux. Do not have the `getconf` to check the same.

Is there a way to check the page size in linux without `getconf`, is it possible to derive it from some proc entries.

Comment: It this about virtual memory page size? OR some other type of page? (edit question to make clear)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495987/86440

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes vm pagesize, edited to reflect same :)

Comment: Do you have full libc?  [`getpagesize()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html) may be available.

Comment: What Operating system? Gnu/Linux or some other Linux based system (What)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux most of the system related information is present under the `/proc/` directory. This includes `PAGESIZE` information, which is in `/proc/self/smaps`.

For example:

```
$ grep -ir pagesize /proc/self/smaps

KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps, not sure how reliable this is.